# How to detect if an --experimental flag is enabled in Node

Tags: node.js

I have some code that needs to work slightly differently depending on whether the `--experimental-vm-modules` is enabled.

I'm currently checking for the presence of an object that only exists if the flag is enabled.

```js
function escapePathForImport(path) {
  // If --experimental-vm-modules is enabled
  // (there may be a better way to detect this)
  if (vm.Module) {
    return path;
  }

  return escape(path);
}
```

That works, but I'm curious if there's a more direct way to detect if a particular `--experimental-*` flag is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [node options documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#options) you may set options via env or CLI args so the following snippet may help to detect activated options:

```
import { env, execArgv } from "node:process";

const flagEnabled =
  (env.NODE_OPTIONS &&
    env.NODE_OPTIONS.match(/experimental(-|_)import(-|_)meta(-|_)resolve/)) ||
  execArgv.some((argv) =>
    argv.match(/experimental(-|_)import(-|_)meta(-|_)resolve/)
  );
```